# Convert string date to YYYYMMDD - VB.NET/SSIS SQL

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

I have got this line

```
Declare @Startdate as Varchar(50)
Set @StartDate = dateadd(dd,-1,convert(datetime, convert(varchar, getdate(),101)))
```

This returns me

> 2014-05-19 00:00:00.000

Now I want to convert above to

```
20140519
```

Can someone please help.

Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this..

```
Declare @Startdate as Varchar(8)

Set @StartDate =  CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE()-1, 112)
SELECT @StartDate 

RESULT: 20140519
```

Answer (score 0):

t-sql's convert method lets you format dates in various ways.

112 looks like the style code you want.